# Print Dijkstra's Algorithm as a tree

Tags: c#, dijkstra

I have the algorithm recording the shortest path of each node and need to print it out as a tree structure... for example:

Vancouver
   - Olympia
       -Lacey
       -Tacoma
          -Seattle

etc... Here is what my node structure is:

```
class DA
{
    public Node Name { get; set; }
    public Node Parent { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public bool Complete { get; set; }

    public DA(Node n)
    {
        Name = n;
        Cost = 100000000;
    }

    public DA() { }
}
```

Here's what I currently print out on the console (format of Parent --> Child Weight
[image]

Any advise on printing this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: OK, that's a nice story you've told us but you seem to have forgotten the point of this site, which is to *ask a question*. What's your question?

Comment: @EricLippert - I just added a clarification for you. I need guidance on printing out the tree structure.

Comment: Also, in what world is the distance from Bellevue to Redmond, which *abut*, longer than Vancouver to Olympia?

Comment: I don't understand the question; how is the shortest path a "tree structure"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
print start.name;
var next = start.next;

while (next) {
  print next.name;
  next = next.next;
}
```

Basically the general idea is to print out the starting location, then keep printing out all of the destination locations, up until you hit the finish.